# select from 2 tables Where if of T1 = id on T2

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

i want to do something like:

```
$dnt = mysql_query('select * from topics WHERE parent != "5" order by timestamp DESC limit 5 ');
while($dnnt = mysql_fetch_array($dnt)){

$dlk = mysql_query('select * from users where id="'.$dnnt['authorid'].'"');

}
```

i think that i need to use something like :

```
$dn1 = mysql_query('select c.XX, c.XXXXX, c.XXX, c.XXX,
(select count(t.XX) from YY as t where t.XXX=c.XX and t.XX1=1) as YY,
(select count(t2.XX) from YY as t2 where t2.XXX=c.XX and t2.XX2!=1) as YYY from YYY as c where c.XXXXX = "...." or c.XXXXX= "..."  group by c.XX order by c.XXX
asc ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT `topics`.*,
       `users`.*
  FROM `topics`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `topics`.`authorid` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `topics`.`parent` != 5
ORDER BY `topics`.`timestamp` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

You should also be advised that the `mysql_*` family of functions is now deprecated. You should look into the use of [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Also, when you use `SELECT *`, you very rarely need **everything**!